# One sunburn peels after 2 days, another after 2 weeks. Why?

Tags: dermatology, sunlight, sun-burn, desquamation-skin-peeling

I once did a long bike ride that burned my legs (low sun intensity/focus, long exposure time). They were immediately sore but didn't peel until 2 weeks later.

I once swum a bit and burned my shoulders (high sun intensity/focus, low exposure time). They were also immediately sore, and peeled only 2 days later.

Was the difference in sun intensity + time exposure responsible for the difference in the time taken for the dead skin to peel?